# Do I need a separate table for facebook login?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

My website has a normal login function. And I want to add another login via facebook api. So do I need a separate table to store facebook data or can I use same table which holds user registration data?

Comment: You can use the same table which holds user registration, just add one extra column `fb_user_id`

Comment: Do I need to store facebook data...Is it essential to create login with facebook function?

Comment: Yes you will need to store the fb data because when user logins for the first time then you will have to register that user internally by checking his email and/or `fb_user_id` if he doesn't exists already. However this is not necessary if you don't have any use of user data.

Comment: Ok..If I add a column for fb_user_id to the table, other columns may be null when a user registered via a facebook. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes other columns may be null but fb also gives email id so if provided then store it too, other information will be filled by user after login..

Comment: please do some research, testing and programming before asking. this would be very clear for you if you would have used facebook login once.

Answer (score 0):

The social media api's return user data, so you could use that data to first check on your database users table whether that user's record exists using the uniqueUserId provided by the api, if not you create a new record.

Example, Github API might return something like;

```
{
    gitHubUserId: 123456,
    username: 'Github Username',
    email: 'user@gmail.com'
}
```

Hope that sheds some light.